# SpringBoot Mockito Testing - mockitoSession NoSuchMethod from MockitoSessionBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am new to JUnit5 and Mockito springboot testing and I am doing a Mockito and JUnit test on my REST service for my Java SpringBoot SpringMVC backend. I am getting a

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.session.MockitoSessionBuilder org.mockito.Mockito.mockitoSession()'
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:149)
```

error during testing although the test is able to run. I highly suspect it is a conflict of my Mockito dependencies in my pom file although I have tried including and excluding various Mockito dependencies from pom but still got the above error. Please help.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fsgsm</groupId>
    <artifactId>kilosteprest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Test App</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
              </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
          </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                         <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                         <version>1.0.1</version>
                     </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my service test file:

```
package com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.model.User;
import com.fsgsm.kilosteprest.repository.UserRepository;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {
        
    @Test
    public void testUserServiceCreation() {     
        //Nothing (no coding) yet in my test method (except this comment) just to test I have added the testing dependencies correctly (or not)     
    }
}
```

My stacktrace is :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.mockito.session.MockitoSessionBuilder org.mockito.Mockito.mockitoSession()'
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)" because the return value of "org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext$Store.remove(Object, java.lang.Class)" is null
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:184)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:253)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:252)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
        ... 45 more
```

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question stop mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5. Ditch the `@RuNWith` and remove the `surefire` plugin from your `pom.xml`. Your pom doesn't include conflicting versions so unless you manually added them to your project in INtellij there is something else messing things up (which you haven't shown). Pro-tip don't use `log4j` (that is unmaintained, use the default logback), pro-tip2, the `spring-boot-starter-web` already includes the `servlet-api` dependency, no need to add it again. pro-tip3: Include `spring-boot-starter-mail` instead of the `javax.mail` dependency.

Comment: Wow! Superb! Thank you Mr Deinum! I hope I can get it working this time and thanks for all the professional tips! I've upvoted your answer.